# Multiple websites on one laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, web, laravel-5, web-applications

I've created a dashboard on laravel with user authentication. I want to create multiple websites on this single laravel application. Each website will belong to one user and each user when log in should see the pages of their own website on the dashboard. Please, help me to do that, any idea or tutorial

Comment: check this link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/multiple-websites-built-on-one-laravel-framework?page=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an interesting project that we are using for this. 
Could you read about Tenancy in this url https://laravel-tenancy.com/